# Program skip lines where i create JTable

Tags: java, swing, class, jdbc, jtable

I created JTable which is populated with data from MySQL database... If there is no needed data in database, then JTable should be empty(except one column, but that is not important).

The thing is, my program just skip that part where JTable Class method is...
Here is my whole code and i just don't know why those lines are skipped...
I hope it is not too long.. I wanted You all to see what i did in class and i will mark where problem is...
I'm sorry for Java naming convention, i had to use some words from my language...

Thank You in advance...

```
public static void popuniTerminiTable() {

    terminDatum = Listener.yearChoose.getSelectedItem() + "-" + (Listener.monthChoose.getSelectedIndex() + 1) + "-" +  TerminiPanel.izabraniDan;
    //System.out.println("terminDatum = " + terminDatum);
    try {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ordinacijaDB";
        String name = "root";
        String password = "admin";

        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url, name, password );


        String checkQuery = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ordinacijadb.zakazivanje WHERE termin = '" + terminDatum + " 7:00:00'");
        Statement checkStmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsCheck = checkStmt.executeQuery(checkQuery);

        int number = 0;

        while(rsCheck.next()) {
            number = rsCheck.getInt("COUNT(*)");
        }

        System.out.println("number = " + number);

        if (number == 0) {
            String queryTimeStamp = ("SELECT TIMESTAMP '" + terminDatum + " 7:00:00'");
            Statement stmtTimeStamp = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rsTimeStamp = stmtTimeStamp.executeQuery(queryTimeStamp);


            while (rsTimeStamp.next()) {
                Timestamp ts = rsTimeStamp.getTimestamp(1);  

                for (int i = 0; i <= 26; i++) {

                    long vreme = ts.getTime(); 

                    vreme1 = new Time(vreme); 
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                    String termin = sdf.format(vreme1); 
                    TerminiPanel.zakazivanjeTableModel.setValueAt(termin, i, 0);

                    String queryPolaSata = ("SELECT DATE_ADD('" + terminDatum + " " + vreme1 +"', INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)");
                    Statement stmtPolaSata = connection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rsPolaSata = stmtPolaSata.executeQuery(queryPolaSata);

                    while(rsPolaSata.next()){
                        ts = rsPolaSata.getTimestamp(1);

                    }
                }
            }
            rsTimeStamp.close();

        } else if(broj == 1)  try {

        Date convertedDate = Date.valueOf(terminDatum);
        String queryUcitajZakazane = ("SELECT * FROM ordinacijaDB.zakazivanje WHERE termin >= '" + convertedDate + " 7:00:00' AND termin <= '" + convertedDate + " 20:00:00'");

        Statement stmtUcitajZakazane = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsUcitajZakazane = stmtUcitajZakazane.executeQuery(queryUcitajZakazane);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rsUcitajZakazane.getMetaData();

        int columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        data1.removeAllElements();


        while (rsUcitajZakazane.next()) {

            Vector podatak = new Vector(columns);

            podatak.removeAllElements();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                    podatak.add( rsUcitajZakazane.getObject(i) );                   
            }
            data1.addElement(podatak);
        }

        connection.close();
        stmtUcitajZakazane.close();
        rsUcitajZakazane.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Vector<String> columnNames1 = new Vector<String>();
    columnNames1.addElement("Termin");
    columnNames1.addElement("Ime i prezime");
    columnNames1.addElement("Napomena");

    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data1, columnNames1); /// LINE ADDED
    JTable zakazivanjeTable1 = new JTable(dtm);   /// LINE ADDED

    zakazivanjeTable1.setRowHeight(27);


    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer(); 
    renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    zakazivanjeTable1.getColumn("Termin").setCellRenderer(renderer);
    zakazivanjeTable1.getColumn("Ime i prezime").setCellRenderer(renderer);
    zakazivanjeTable1.getColumn("Napomena").setCellRenderer(renderer);

    TableColumn column;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        column = zakazivanjeTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(5);
        } else {
            column.setPreferredWidth(170);
       }
    }
    System.out.println("pred dodavanje");
    JScrollPane terminiScrollPane = new JScrollPane(zakazivanjeTable1);
    TerminiPanel.terminPanel.removeAll();
    TerminiPanel.terminPanel.add(TerminiPanel.buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    TerminiPanel.terminPanel.add(terminiScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    TerminiPanel.terminPanel.revalidate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by, `"my program just skip that part where JTable Class method is"`? Please tell us clearly and precisely exactly what is happening. And what "lines" do you feel are involved or are "skipped"?

Comment: It looks like you want to add a `getColumnClass` method for your JTable, but you're not using the right syntax.

Comment: I marked in code lines that are skipped.. Program does not process them and i don't know why...
I placed System.out.println("random text"); before and after those lines and program print that random text...
if i add System.out.println("random text");  somewhere between those skipped lines in code, that "random text" is not printed or shown so i guess program skip that part of my code...

Comment: What type is `data1`?

Comment: data1 is Vector . . .

Comment: @Mlad3n What exactly are you trying to do on those lines? I'm pretty sure it boils down to incorrect syntax; the curly braces almost certainly aren't doing what you think they are.

Comment: i just want to make JTable with (data1, columnNames1) but for some reason i cant write only JTable tableName = new JTable(data1, columnNames1).
It worked like this as You see it in my code up there (with Class method) but i needed to add check if number = 0 or number = 1...
Now after i added it, program skip these lines and doesnt make JTable

Comment: and something else.. i already did the same thing with other table in my program and all works fine so i guess it is not the syntax problem... That is why i am so confused and cant find solution anywhere on internet :-/

Comment: Is there any particular reason that method absolutely has to be right there? What's stopping you from having it as a separate method as normal?

Comment: I replaced that whole method with 
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data1, columnNames1);
  JTable zakazivanjeTable1 = new JTable(dtm);

But JTable is not shown again :-/

Comment: Then if you're still having the same problem, do you mind posting the updated code?

Comment: There, i edited code.. No more Class method, but still there is no JTable shown :-/
Also strange thing is, i get JTable header with column names, but not rest of the table...

Comment: Since you're not getting an answer, your best bet here is to show us compilable code. We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem, in other words, an SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example). For more info on SSCCEs please look here: [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

1. don't to create an `JComponents` inside `try - catch - finally` block, on 1st exception is everything skipped and executed is `catch` block (then `finally` block), empty GUI could be simple reason,
2. create all `JComponents` as local variables, then is this Object accesible from all corners in current JVM
3. don't to recreate `JComponents`, all `Swing JComponents` has own model, reuse this model, valid for all `Swing JComponents` are designated to be reusable (e.g `TerminiPanel.terminPanel.removeAll(); ---> TerminiPanel.terminPanel.revalidate()`;)
4. put all `Statements` together, because looks like as they are chained from `JCalendar value(???)`, thera are a bunch of MySQL tutorials,
5. `close()` all `JDBC Object` in the `finally` block, otherise stays and increasing JVM used memory
6. search (here on this forum, milion times here) for `ResultSetTableModel`, `TableFromDatabase`, for easy, clear and quite safe `JDBC _ to _ JTable`
7. for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable caused a.m. issue with hardcode value in local variable for JTable instead of any (shadowing whatever can be stored there) `JDBC` code
8. before anything to read `Oracles tutorials` about `try-catch-finally` and `JTable` there especially part `creating table model`

Comment: mKorbel, I think Your 1. advice is the reason... 6th one is not in place because i was looking all over and didn't find anything that i could use...
Sorry if I took some of Your time, guys.. I will do something about this tomorow
Thanks again